# example.com redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I was trying to Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 16.04.

example.conf file **before** obtaining an SSL Certificate

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com ;
    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/backup/mycode/public;
    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/wrappers/ruby;

}
```

http://example.com/ is **working fine.**

I try to Obtain an SSL Certificate by

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

the result was

```
Your existing certificate has been successfully renewed, and the new certificate
has been installed.

The new certificate covers the following domains: https://example.com and
https://www.example.com
```

example.conf file **after** obtaining an SSL Certificate

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com ;
    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/backup/example.com/public;
    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/wrappers/ruby;




    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.com www.example.com ;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

http://example.com/ is redirecting to   https://example.com/ too many times

```
example.com redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

1. Why is it redirecting too many times?
2. what is the purpose of the second server block?

   ```
   server {
   if ($host = www.example.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot


   if ($host = example.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot


   server_name example.com www.example.com ;
   listen 80;
   return 404; # managed by Certbot

    }
   ```
3. How to make all redirects to https://www.example.com/?

EDIT1

Moving the certibot managed code to second server block has stopped the too many redirects problem. But my website is back again directing to **HTTP** instead of https.

```
server {
            server_name example.com www.example.com ;
            # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
            root /var/www/backup/example.com/public;
            # Turn on Passenger
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env development;
            passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/wrappers/ruby;

        }
        server {

            listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
            include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
            if ($host = www.example.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            } # managed by Certbot


            if ($host = example.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            } # managed by Certbot


            server_name example.com www.example.com ;
            listen 80;
            return 404; # managed by Certbot

        }
```

Comment: Your config looks fine. The new `server` block redirects HTTP to HTTPS. Check your browser cache and your application.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the purpose of the second server block?

To listen on HTTP and redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.

> Why is it redirecting too many times?

It should not, *unless* the web site itself doesn't like being called using HTTPS and performs some redirect again. The Nginx config seems to be fine.

```
How to make all redirects to https://www.example.com/?
```

Change

```
if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

to

```
if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

You can also add another redirect from https://example.com to https://www.example.com (in the first server block, the one listening on HTTPS); this will take care of redirecting HTTPS requests without "www." at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Why is it redirecting too many times?**

Your application isn't aware if the request came in over SSL or not, adding the following line to your server block should fix it:

`passenger_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`